# What are possible merits of @Startup@Singleton over @Stateless with @Schedule service?

Tags: timer, singleton, ejb, startup

I'm separating my business methods and scheduled methods.

What are possible merits of following code

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MySchedule {

    @Schedule(...)
    public void doSome() {
    }
}
```

over following code?

```
@Stateless
public class MySchedule {

    @Schedule(...)
    public void doSome() {
    }
}
```

I read definitions of `@Singleton` and `@Startup`. But I see the method of the class annotated solely with `@Stateless` also works as scheduled.

Is there any differences or preferences?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the container implementation (and EJB spec).

A @Stateless will act as is and you should not have a state in it!
The method is invoked for each schedule, Wildfly will prevent from concurrent call, the schedule will be skipped with a WARN message if the timer is still running (i.e. 1minute schedule and the execution take more)

A @Singleton might keep a state (i.e. start initialization) and during the scheduled events.
By spec you can't invoke this instance concurrent until you add Lock.READ, this mean as long as the scheduler run you are not able to invoke any other method.
For concurrent schedule of the same it is not possible anyway (see above)
That mean also you can not run two @Schedule methods at the same time as well.

I'm not sure whether other containers allow concurrent execution for timers.

If you have a single schedule (and nothing else in the implementation) it should not make a difference.
And the @Startup will not make much sense then also ;)